# Reverse source code and double the input

Tags: code-golf, string, source-layout

For today's challenge you have to take an input, and if your source code is reversed, then the input should be printed doubled.

Let's say your source code is `ABC` and its input is `xyz`. If I write `CBA` instead and run it, the output must be any of be `xyzxyz` or `xyz xyz` or

```
xyz 
xyz
```

For any numerical input you should not multiply it with `2`, instead use the upper rule, for input `1` ->  `11` or `1 1` or

```
1
1
```

(Trailing newlines allowed in output, but not the leading ones)

For simplicity, you can assume that the input is always a single line string containing only ASCII letters (a-z), digits (0-9) and spaces. (You will not get empty input)

Standard loopholes apply, shortest code wins

original source code's output can be anything

Comment: What is the output for original source code?

Comment: @AZTECCO for original source output can be anything

Comment: @Daemon So if original source is a palindrome that directly prints the input doubled, then that is allowed too?

Comment: What are the requirements for the original source?

Comment: @ManishKundu output should not be hard coded and you must take an input

Comment: Can the output be empty for original source?

Comment: @Wasif yes can be

Comment: The challenge wouldn't be very interesting if the original source has no restriction (ex. a solution with a trailing comment would suffice)

Comment: @Daemon As you can see, your challenge spec isn't the most popular. Consider using [the Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges) next time, to avoid such situations.

Comment: @Daemon You have posted 6 challenges of which 4 have negative total score. You have never answered any challenges yourself. I highly recommend answering some existing challenges before venturing into writing your own, as that will give you some insight into what makes for a good, well-specified challenge.

Answer (score 5):

## Trivial comment trick

### JavaScript (ES6), 12 bytes

```javascript
s=>s//s+s>=s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lYyxCsIwFEV3vyJk6Qumr3SW5Cc6itASX0tKSCSvBHXw12M7ObtcOHDOXacyscv@sbUx3am6fYQRY2Vjuev4zNZwHZGDdwS9Fm2vLqd5V6hMAQ59Z5cip0AY0gIzbmnYso8LKC3kx0otZpDP11sq9SuviHjUN8xUKDOBwjX5CE2j/nmsXw)

Answer (score 4):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 1 [byte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
p
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=cA&input=IjEi)

- Returns S repeated n times with n defaulted to 2.

Comment: How can 1 byte of code have different behaviour when reversed?

Comment: @Adám Abuses the rule "original source code can be anything " by doubling the input too, loopholes allowed

Comment: Oh, I see. OP gets my downvote too, then.

Comment: @Adám lol, I feel so sad for OP.. People should take more care to advices!

Comment: works also for sed

Comment: @Nahuel Fouilleul yes [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K05N0U3PK/3/v@D//4rKKgA "sed – Try It Online")

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) (`-0777p` `-M5.01`), 3 bytes

```perl
yas
```

reversed

```perl
say
```

- `-0777` to undef input record separator (slurp input).
- `-p` option print default argument (input) to output.
- `-M5.01` to use `say` shorter than `print`
- `yas` : bareword (same as "yas" with the quotes), no-op.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/78ysfj//4rKqn/5BSWZ@XnF/3UNzM3NC/7r@prqGRgCAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 8 bytes

```powershell
#2*sgra$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/X9lIqzi9KFHl////FZVVAA)

[!enilno ti yrT](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/XyWxKL1Yy0j5////FZVVAA)

-6 bytes thanks to @NauhelFouilleul

Comment: or maybe just `#2*sgra$ `because the output can be empty for original source

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul thanks!

Answer (score 2):

## [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg), `-no`, 2 bytes

```
#:
```

[Don't try it online!](https://tio.run/##y05N//9f2er//4zU5GwA)

Ah yes, bad language design at it's finest. You can't try it online because it desperately needs a pull - and Dennis hasn't been around for a while.

The `-no` flag makes everything output as-is - without it, numbers would attempt to output as characters (not very helpful)

### Explained

```
#:
```

Do nothing: standard cat program

```
:#
```

Duplicate the top of the stack and output the entire stack

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 3 bytes

Anonymous tacit prefix function.

```apl
,,,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///X0dH53/ao7YJj3r7HnU1P@pd86h3y6H1xo/aJj7qmxoc5AwkQzw8g/@nKahXVFapAwA)

The outer commas ravel (flatten) the argument to a simple string (i.e. a no-op).

The middle comma is concatenation.

The whole function concatenates the string to itself.

Since all characters are identical, this works when reversed too.

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 2 bytes

```
#d
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%23d&inputs=Heck&header=&footer=)

Very good trivial answer. Make sure to wrap input in double quotation marks.

### Explained

```
#d
```

Nothing, a standard cat program

```
d#
```

Double the input string and output.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 2 bytes

```
zz
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/v6rq//@KyioA)

`z` -> Prints the input.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 17 bytes

```python
#)2*)(tupni(tnirp
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/X1nTSEtTo6S0IC9ToyQvs6jg//@KyioA)

[!enilno ti yrT](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69EIzOvoLREQ1PLSFP5//@KyioA)

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://php.net/) -F, 15 bytes

```php
;ngra$.ngra$=?<
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fOi@9KFFFD0za2tv8/19RWfUvv6AkMz@v@L@uGwA)

[Try it reversed!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxt5WJbEoPU8PTFr//19RWfUvv6AkMz@v@L@uGwA)

---

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 13 bytes

```php
i$.i$>=)i$(nf
```

Outputs error when not reversed.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jX5BRwKWSZvs/U0UvU8XOVjNTRSMv7b81V2pyRr6CSpqGUkVllZKm9X8A)

[Try it reversed!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jX5BRwKWSZvs/LU9DJVPT1k4lU08l8781V2pyRr6CSpqGUkVllZKm9X8A)

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E (legacy)](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/tree/fb4a2ce2bce6660e1a680a74dd61b72c945e6c3b), 2 bytes

```
x#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f@/QhmIK6sA)

[!enilno ti yrT](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f9fueL//4rKKgA)

`x` doubles the input

Comment: Please ignore my previous comment. A note to people testing this out: you need to surround numbers with quotation marks for it to work with numbers

Comment: `JD` also works and doesn't require numbers to be quoted.

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 3 bytes

```
²×⁰
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5///QpsPTHzVu@P8/pKhSIbNEIT8vJzMvVZELAA) Outputs `--`.

```
⁰×²
```

[!enilno ti yrT](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5//9R44bD0w9t@v8/pKhSIbNEIT8vJzMvVZELAA) Explanation: Outputs zero `-`s, then doubles the implicit input.

Charcoal normally takes string input, but you can force it to take numeric input. There are various ways of constructing a 5-byte program that forces string output, although in that case the unreversed output will no longer be `--`.

The assumes that both programs need to be syntactically valid, as Charcoal will normally ignore invalid programs rather than exiting with error. Abusing this would allow the programs to be reduced to 2 and 3 bytes respectively.

Answer (score 0):

## Batch, 16 bytes

```
@ rem&1%1% ohce@
```

```
@echo %1%1&rem @
```

Answer (score 0):

## [YaBASIC](http://www.yabasic.de), 8 bytes

```
//$i,$i?
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##q0xMSizOTP6fqWKrVFFZpaSgr68QkpGqkJlXUFryX19fJVNHJdP@/38A)

```
?i$,i$//
```

[!enilno ti yrT](https://tio.run/##q0xMSizOTP6fqWKrVFFZpaSgr68QkpGqkJlXUFry3z5TRSdTRV///38A)

A basic BASIC answer - hide the reversed source behind a comment! Original does nothing, reversed prints input i$ twice. This dialect recognizes // as a comment. I'd shave a byte if it would accept ' like Microsoft BASIC variations do!

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 1 bytes

*Ties [AZTECCO's Japt answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/220370/reverse-source-code-and-double-the-input/220381#220381) for #1.*

```
«
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//0Or//ysqqwA)

[!enilno ti yrT](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//0Or//ysqqwA)

```
«  # full program
   # implicit input...
«  # concatenated with...
   # implicit input
   # implicit output
```